# NullReferenceException, How to initialize member class Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor, nullreferenceexception

I have a page with with a simple form within it that it bound to my model's member class, I am getting the following error

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

My page(shown below), works fine if I don't use `Timelineinfos`, but when I do reference it I get the error. So my question is: How should I initialize `Timelineinfos`?

```cs
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-7">
        <EditForm Model="test">
            <InputText @bind-Value="test.Timelineinfos.City"></InputText>
        </EditForm>
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    public testmodel test = new testmodel();

    public class testmodel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Timelineinfo Timelineinfos { get; set; }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the exception is that we haven't initialized the value of `Timelineinfos`, leaving it `null`, and then try to access a member of it by binding `test.Timelineinfos.City`. Because there is no instance of `Timelineinfos`, that amounts to `null.City` which is, of course, meaningless.

You may initialize the value a number of ways.

Via the constructor using an object initializer:

```
public testmodel test = new testmodel() { Timelineinfos = new Timelineinfo() };
```

... which is syntactic sugar for the following:

```
testmodel test = new testmodel();
test.Timelineinfos = new Timelineinfo();
```

By implementing a default for the property:

```
public Timelineinfo Timelineinfos { get; set; } = new Timelineinfos();
```

... which is essentially the same as setting them in the default (parameterless) constructor:

```
public testmodel()
{
    this.Timelineinfos = new Timelineinfos();
}
```

In any case, once you have an instance, your NullReferenceException will be no more.